# Is there a django ORM version of this SQL statement?

Tags: python, django, django-orm, postgresql-9.4, postgresql-json

Using Django 1.9 and Postgres 9.4.

I have a jsonb field called `json_field`. `json_field` can contain the key `title` which could look like `'the cow jumped over the moon'`.

So I want to search for rows where `title` contains `moon`.

It works properly using the following raw SQL

`SELECT * FROM web_file where (json_field ->> 'title')::text LIKE '%moon%';`

but I'd rather do it using the Django ORM.

EDIT:

I thought to try (and as pointed out by @kloddant)

```
title = WebFile.objects.filter(json_field__title__contains='moon')
```

but it gives the following error

```
DataError: invalid input syntax for type json
LINE 1: ...le" WHERE "web_file"."json_field" -> 'title' @> 'moon' ORD...
                                                            ^
DETAIL:  Token "moon" is invalid.
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: moon
```

Here is the relevant `models.py`

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField

class WebFile(MPTTModel):
    json_field = JSONField(null=True, blank=True, default=dict())
```

It could be a clash between the django model and MPTTModel, although Im doubtful?

Comment: Where does JSONField field type comes from? It is not part of Django and it is not part of MPTT.

Comment: @MadWombat its new in Django 1.9 https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield

Comment: You might want to read the docs. JSONField is not a string, so it looks like `__contains` filter might not work same as it does with string.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#querying-jsonfield

Comment: reading a bit more, looks like you need to pass a dictionary to __contains

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/

You would do something like:

```
WebFile.objects.filter(json_field__title__contains='moon')
```

Comment: I thought the same, but it appears not to work:

`
DataError: invalid input syntax for type json
LINE 1: ...le" WHERE "web_file"."json_field" -> 'title' @> 'moon' ORD...
                                                                                           ^
DETAIL:  Token "moon" is invalid.
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: moon
`

Comment: That is just weird. Does `WebFile.object.filter(json_field__title='moon')` work (by work I mean does it find things with the title 'moon', I realize it won't give you what you want)? Maybe it is something to do with the `__contains`?

Answer (score 0):

```
title = WebFile.objects.filter(title__icontains=moon)
```

Of course, you have to have the WebFile model created first and import it at the top of your page from the models.py file.

Comment: that wont work because `title` is contained in the `json_field`

Comment: If you have a json object within your database field, then I would consider restructuring your database, if possible, so that all the json data is in a separate table that is linked to the webfile table with a foreign key.

Comment: there are use cases where an application user would like to create their own schema-less key value pairs, and I don't want to make a new table for each user. I think my use case is pretty aligned with what Postgres 9.4 jsonb can do.

Comment: @kloddant no restructuring required. JSON fields are a feature of PostgreSQL and have plenty of real use cases. It's not to be used in place of a NoSQL database, but definitely has cases where it is useful, especially with Django's built in Postgres fields.

Answer (score 0):

Are you not using a `JSONField` from `django.contrib.postgres.fields`? In that case, it would just be something [like this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#key-index-and-path-lookups):

```
WebFile.objects.filter(json_field__title__contains='moon')
```

Can you post the relevant `models.py`? Also, if you're not using `django.contrib.postgres.fields` and relying on default models (like manually extending a `CharField` or something), you're going to have a hard time.

Comment: I have posted the `model.py`

Comment: Did you try the approach I posted? The problem is that you can't filter the object on `title` because `title` is not an attribute of `WebFile`. Also, your `default` should be callable. Use `dict` for an empty default. From the documentation: "Incorrectly using default={} creates a mutable default that is shared between all instances of JSONField."

Comment: Yes, I have tried your approach and I receive an error (I have included the error in my question). Thanks for the pointer on the default.